# How to package Scrapy dependency to lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, scrapy

I am writing a python application which dependents on `Scrapy` module. It works fine locally but failed when I run it from aws lambda test console. My python project has a `requirements.txt` file with below dependency:

```
scrapy==1.6.0
```

I packaged all dependencies by following this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html. And also, I put my source code `*.py` at the root level of in the zip file. My package script can be found `https://github.com/zhaoyi0113/quote-datalake/blob/master/bin/deploy.sh`.

It basically does two things, first run command `pip install -r requirements.txt -t dist` to download all dependencies to `dist` directory. second, copy app python source code to `dist` directory.

The deployment is done via `terraform` and below is the configuration file.

```
provider "aws" {
  profile    = "default"
  region     = "ap-southeast-2"
}

variable "runtime" {
  default = "python3.6"
}

data "archive_file" "zipit" {
    type        = "zip"
    source_dir  = "crawler/dist"
    output_path = "crawler/dist/deploy.zip"
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename      = "crawler/dist/deploy.zip"
  function_name = "quote-crawler"
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::773592622512:role/LambdaRole"
  handler       = "handler.handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.zipit.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime = "${var.runtime}"
}
```

It zip the directory and upload the file to lambda.

I found I get the runtime error in lambda `Unable to import module 'handler': cannot import name 'etree'` when there is a statement `import scrapy`. I didn't use `etree` in my code so I believe there is something used by `scrapy`.

My source code can be found at `https://github.com/zhaoyi0113/quote-datalake/tree/master/crawler`. There are only two simple python files.

It works fine if I run them locally. The error only appears in lambda. Is there a different way to package `scrapy` to lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the entire dependency tree, *scrapy* also has a set of dependencies (and they may also have dependencies).

The easiest way to download all the required dependencies is to use pip

```sh
$ pip -t packages/ install scrapy
```

This will download *scrapy* and all its dependencies into the folder packages.

Scrapy has `lxml` and `pyOpenSSL` as dependencies that include compiled components. Unless they are statically compiled they will likely require that the c-libraries they require are also installed on the lambda VM.

From the lxml documentation it requires:

- libxml2 version 2.9.2 or later.
- libxslt version 1.1.27 or later.
  We recommend libxslt 1.1.28 or later.

Maybe try adding installation of these to your deploy script. You should be able to use (I'm making a guess at the package names) `yum -y install libxml2 libxslt`

Another good idea is to test your scripts on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance as this is close to the environment that Lambda executes in.

Comment: which pip version are you using? My `pip 19.1.1` doesn't support `-d` parameter.  What I am using is `pip install -r requirements.txt -t dist` which downloads all depdencies to `dist` directory. Does it work as same as your command?

Comment: Sorry yes it has changed to `-t`

Comment: I already tried that but still the same issue happens. Did I miss any dependencies in my project?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some additional info. Likely you are running into issues with CExtensions. In the past I've had to compile these on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance. I was doing a lot of work with Lambda in my previous job and am recalling what I had setup.

Comment: I have added `lxml` and `pyOpenSSL` on `requirements.txt` and installed the depednencies you mentioned on `ubuntu`. The compile works fine but still get the same error from lambda. The OS I am using is `18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)`.

Comment: I'd still test on Amazon Linux EC2 instance. You might find it has compiled correctly but the .so is not loading correctly or is unable to resolve the correct library at runtime. I've had to symlink libraries into other locations before to resolve this issue. To save a lot of headaches we would get source packages and compile them on an Amazon Linux instance ensuring they are compatible.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I am using docker to solve my issue. This is the command: `docker run -v $(pwd):/outputs -it --rm lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 pip install scrapy -t /outputs/`

Comment: Yes that would do it as well. Maybe write that up as an answer.

Comment: Yep, posted the answer.

Comment: What would you put in the requirements.txt file to install scrapy and its dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the communication with Tim, the issue is caused by incompatible library versions between local and lambda.

The easiest way to resolve this issue is to use the docker image `lambci/lambda` to build a package with the command:

```sh
$ docker run -v $(pwd):/outputs -it --rm lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 pip install scrapy -t /outputs/
```